# How to redeploy gcloud beta function

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I am working with Dialogflow at the moment using [this guide](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation). The guide gives me directions how to upload a function to the google cloud storage with the command

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloTest --stage-bucket helloStorage --trigger-http
```

This works fine. I then wanted to make some changes to the code and redeploy it. I ran the same code again, but this time it just creates another zip file in the storage and my function wasn't updated or working anymore until i deleted the older function zip file.

Any ideas? I am using ubuntu to do this .

[image: google storage]

Comment: Cloud Support here! This is not an expected behaviour. Can you  go here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195 and raise an issue with your project number (not the project ID). After that post the link of the public issue in a comment here please. This way I'll be able to further help you